# jQuery toggleClass working but not animating

Tags: jquery, animation, toggleclass

This code `$(this).data('parentWidget').toggleClass(COLLAPSE_CLASS, 1000);` bound to a button click, is successfully toggling the COLLAPSE_CLASS on and off. However, the effect is not animating.

In the css, the original element has a defined height:85px. When the collapse class is added .collapse { height:20px; } only the height changes.

As I mentioned, this works like a charm in terms of toggling the height. What I don't see is any kind of transition effect. What are the conditions under which such a simple transition effect might not work? Needless to say the [jQuery documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/toggleClass/) on the subject is sparse.

Comment: Possibly a silly question, but are you actually running jQuery UI?

Comment: If you mean, was I loading the jQuery UI core + transitions, then.... um.... DOH!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For others who may be imbeciles like myself, do make sure you're actually loading your jQuery.ui.core.js files (or build a custom jquery ui version). My example is in the context of WordPress and I naively assumed that it was loading jQueryUI. Apparently toggleClass is part of jquery.core (so the toggling part works no matter what), but the transition depends on jquery.ui.core (and maybe others? not sure)